# Conditions for some indexes of the Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

How use conditions for some Thinking Sphinx indexes? For some reasons I needed a condition like this:

...

```
has values(:id), **where(this_value.type_id => 1)**
has values(:id), **where(this_value.type_id => 2)**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something like this, you need to get your hands dirty with a bit of SQL. There are some concatenation commands that depend on what database you're using... first, here's an example for PostgreSQL:

```
has "array_to_string(array_remove(array_agg(CASE WHEN values.type_id = 1 THEN values.id ELSE NULL END CASE), NULL), ',')",
  :as => :first_value_ids, :type => :integer, :multi => true
```

In MySQL, it could look more like this:

```
has "GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN values.type_id = 1 THEN values.id ELSE NULL END CASE) SEPARATOR ',')",
  :as => :first_value_ids, :type => :integer, :multi => true
```

If you're not yet using Thinking Sphinx v3, then the options should become `:as => :first_value_ids, :type => :multi`.

These queries haven't been tested, and I'd recommend confirming they work properly, but the theory is sound.

Also, if you're not using the values association anywhere else in your index definition in a normal manner, you'll need to ensure there's a join with the following within your index definition:

```
join values
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
has values(:id), as: :value_ids, type: :integer if this_value.type_id => 1
```

this was tested on

Sphinx 3.3.1
thinking-sphinx 5.1.0
mySQL 8.0.23
MacOS 10.15.7